# lua api unknow types and count of arguments

Tags: c, api, lua

I have got a function following:

```
int Lua_Func(lua_State* L)
{
    int argCount = lua_gettop(L);
    return 0;
}
```

And i wonder to know how can i get parameters with unknow types. For example i want to pass this :

```
myfunc("string",1,{"xxx",xxx",1})
```

How can i get all the parameters by types?

I couldnt try anything because i am kinda noob of this knowladge.

Comment: did you try `lua_isboolean`, `lua_isnumber`, `lua_isstring`, etc?

Comment: @user253751 no, but i can make a loop and then i can do it right ?

Comment: yes...........?

Comment: and 1 more question @user253751

could i pass address like base+0x00 to lua_register for register function

Comment: switch on `lua_type`. see https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lauxlib.c.html#luaL_tolstring for instance.

Comment: Lua C functions has no limitations on types or count of arguments. C function is repsonsible to validate the arguments and count of arguments. You must read the documentation how it works: https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html#P4. And simple example: https://www.lua.org/pil/26.1.html